# Tileserver-gl with Varnish always giving Age: 0 for the pbf

Tags: nginx, varnish, tileserver-gl

I am using tileserver-gl and want to use Varnish to cache the tiles. Varnish is working with nginx, that is taking care of the SSL.
The pbf tiles return Age:0 in the header (and a MISS), while the Date and Expires headers keep their value between reloads. What am I doing wrong?
In nginx I am using the following parameters

```
expires 2d;
add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
```

Here's my .vcl

```
sub vcl_recv {
  unset req.http.cookie; #added as a test, nothing changed so don't know if I should keep it
}
sub vcl_backend_response {
}
sub vcl_deliver {
  if (obj.hits > 0) { # Add debug header to see if it's a HIT/MISS and the number of hits
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
  } else {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
  }
}
```

Here's response header for one of the pbf tiles. They all give similar results, with Age: 0

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Age: 0
Cache-Control: max-age=172800, public, no-transform
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 44891
Content-Type: application/x-protobuf
Date: Fri, 09 Dec 2022 10:30:34 GMT
ETag: W/"af5b-yQTY5UUgiSJNWC0axguA5dmojbI"
Expires: Sun, 11 Dec 2022 10:30:34 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 23 Nov 2022 09:25:23 GMT
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.6)
X-Cache: MISS
X-Varnish: 557061
```

**EDIT**

Tried [Thijs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12892695/thijs-feryn) suggestion, here's the output

```
*   << Request  >> 98318
-   Begin          req 98317 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1670854870.784403 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1670854870.784403 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 38402 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /data/2017-07-03_europe_italy/0/0/0.pbf
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: tiles.urbismap.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Real_IP: 93.41.126.66
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 93.41.126.66
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      Host: tiles.urbismap.com
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: */*
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
-   ReqHeader      Referer: https://tiles.urbismap.com/styles/basemap/
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 93.41.126.66
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 93.41.126.66, 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_return     hash
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 98319 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1670854870.792969 0.008566 0.008566
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
-   RespHeader     Date: Mon, 12 Dec 2022 14:21:10 GMT
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: application/x-protobuf
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 31578
-   RespHeader     Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     Last-Modified: Wed, 23 Nov 2022 09:25:23 GMT
-   RespHeader     ETag: W/"7b5a-Lgi1EP0ZRDWVK1iX+VP47MXHk2M"
-   RespHeader     Expires: Wed, 14 Dec 2022 14:21:10 GMT
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=172800, public, no-transform
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 98318
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.6)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespHeader     X-Cache: MISS
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1670854870.793004 0.008600 0.000034
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1670854870.794239 0.009835 0.001235
-   ReqAcct        555 0 555 524 31578 32102
-   End
**  << BeReq    >> 98319
--  Begin          bereq 98318 fetch
--  VCL_use        boot
--  Timestamp      Start: 1670854870.784497 0.000000 0.000000
--  BereqMethod    GET
--  BereqURL       /data/2017-07-03_europe_italy/0/0/0.pbf
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: tiles.urbismap.com
--  BereqHeader    X-Real_IP: 93.41.126.66
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
--  BereqHeader    Host: tiles.urbismap.com
--  BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
--  BereqHeader    Accept: */*
--  BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
--  BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
--  BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
--  BereqHeader    Referer: https://tiles.urbismap.com/styles/basemap/
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9
--  BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 93.41.126.66, 127.0.0.1
--  BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
--  BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
--  BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 98319
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
--  VCL_return     fetch
--  Timestamp      Fetch: 1670854870.784543 0.000045 0.000045
--  Timestamp      Connected: 1670854870.784548 0.000050 0.000005
--  BackendOpen    31 default 127.0.0.1 8080 127.0.0.1 41766 reuse
--  Timestamp      Bereq: 1670854870.784608 0.000111 0.000060
--  Timestamp      Beresp: 1670854870.792781 0.008283 0.008172
--  BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
--  BerespStatus   200
--  BerespReason   OK
--  BerespHeader   Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
--  BerespHeader   Date: Mon, 12 Dec 2022 14:21:10 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Content-Type: application/x-protobuf
--  BerespHeader   Content-Length: 31578
--  BerespHeader   Connection: keep-alive
--  BerespHeader   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
--  BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
--  BerespHeader   Last-Modified: Wed, 23 Nov 2022 09:25:23 GMT
--  BerespHeader   ETag: W/"7b5a-Lgi1EP0ZRDWVK1iX+VP47MXHk2M"
--  BerespHeader   Expires: Wed, 14 Dec 2022 14:21:10 GMT
--  BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=172800
--  BerespHeader   Cache-Control: public, no-transform
--  TTL            RFC 172800 10 0 1670854871 1670854871 1670854870 1671027670 172800 cacheable
--  VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
--  VCL_return     deliver
--  Timestamp      Process: 1670854870.792827 0.008329 0.000046
--  Filters         testgunzip
--  BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
--  Storage        malloc s0
--  Fetch_Body     3 length stream
--  Gzip           u F - 31578 51339 80 141523 252560
--  BackendClose   31 default recycle
--  Timestamp      BerespBody: 1670854870.794161 0.009664 0.001334
--  Length         31578
--  BereqAcct      552 0 552 426 31578 32004
--  End









*   << Request  >> 98350
-   Begin          req 98349 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1670855034.759301 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1670855034.759301 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       127.0.0.1 47736 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /data/2017-07-03_europe_italy/0/0/0.pbf
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: tiles.urbismap.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Real_IP: 93.41.126.66
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 93.41.126.66
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      Host: tiles.urbismap.com
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: */*
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
-   ReqHeader      Referer: https://tiles.urbismap.com/styles/basemap/
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 93.41.126.66
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 93.41.126.66, 127.0.0.1
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   VCL_return     hash
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   Hit            98319 172636.033479 10.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_call       HIT
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     200
-   RespReason     OK
-   RespHeader     Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
-   RespHeader     Date: Mon, 12 Dec 2022 14:21:10 GMT
-   RespHeader     Content-Type: application/x-protobuf
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 31578
-   RespHeader     Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
-   RespHeader     Content-Encoding: gzip
-   RespHeader     Last-Modified: Wed, 23 Nov 2022 09:25:23 GMT
-   RespHeader     ETag: W/"7b5a-Lgi1EP0ZRDWVK1iX+VP47MXHk2M"
-   RespHeader     Expires: Wed, 14 Dec 2022 14:21:10 GMT
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: max-age=172800, public, no-transform
-   RespHeader     Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 98350 98319
-   RespHeader     Age: 163
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.6)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespHeader     X-Cache: HIT
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1670855034.759391 0.000089 0.000089
-   Filters
-   RespHeader     Accept-Ranges: bytes
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1670855034.759479 0.000177 0.000087
-   ReqAcct        555 0 555 531 31578 32109
-   End
```

Comment: Can you please run the following command? `varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/path/to/pbf'"`. Since I don't know the URL of your requests, I suggested a hypothetical one. Please correct the URL and attach the output of this command to your question. Please ensure that send 2 HTTP requests for that URL to ensure that a potential cache hit takes place, knowing it probably won't.

Comment: Tried this, I'm not seeing anything. If I use just varnishlog i see some of the requests, specifically the ones that give a HIT in the inspector. By the way this is the URL for the requests, if it may be of use: https://tiles.urbismap.com/styles/basemap/

Comment: I checked https://tiles.urbismap.com/styles/basemap/#0.93/0/0 and noticed that the tiles are served from a different host name `services.arcgisonline.com`.  Are you sure that  the hostname `services.arcgisonline.com` is also managed by  your Varnish server?

Comment: I am serving two sets of tiles: the raster tiles for the satellite images are served by arcgis and are not cached by varnish; the vector tiles for the roads and such are instead served from varnish, like this one: https://tiles.urbismap.com/data/2017-07-03_europe_italy/0/0/0.pbf

Comment: OK, so let's try this logging command then: `varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/data/2017-07-03_europe_italy/0/0/0.pbf'"`. This is the exact PBF file you mentioned. Try triggering it and see how it flows through Varnish by using the `varnishlog` command. If it doesn't appear, it means Varnish is not handling it. If it does appear in the logs, add the output to the question and I'll investigate. Don't forget to run it twice to simulate a potential cache hit after the first cache miss.

Comment: Tried what you suggested and now I'm getting a HIT. But I had to make the calls from an Hidden Session on Chrome to have them trigger on the logs, since I was not getting anything. After that, I noticed that the Age count in the normal session is always 163, so I'm guessing that the browser is somehow caching the response (if so, how can I prevent it to do it?)

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer. I had the "disable cache" in the Chrome Network Inspector unchecked... checking that I see consistent HIT / MISS and Age values in the responses. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For these types of tests I always use `curl`. I would run the following command to debug the `pbf` file: `curl -I https://tiles.urbismap.com/data/2017-07-03_europe_italy/0/0/0.pbf`.